# js replace global doesn't like +?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

So I've been playing around with the replace function (method?) in js.

```
$get('msgBar').replace(/+/g,' ');
```

Let's say the content of $get('msgBar') is "Welcome+back+now".

`replace('+',' ')` would only replace the first +, and not the second.

`replace(/+/g,' ')` crashes

`replace(/"+"/g,' ')` and `replace(/\+/g,' ')` are both the same as the first

I'm sure the solution is easy... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must quote +:

```
$get('msgBar').replace(/\+/g,' ');
```

'+' is a meta character, like '*'. It means "one more repetitions". It you literally want '+' , then you have to quote it with the backslash.

Comment: Specifically, you must quote it because '+' has meaning in regular expressions, and the first argument to replace is used as a regex, not a bare string for comparison...

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that (as in the original post), and it didn't work for whatever reason... that is, only the first + is replaced.

Comment: No you didn't. You forgot the 'g' - it means "global match" and instructs regex to find and replace **all** matches.

Comment: T'was a typo. I copied and pasted your solution and it did not work. Sorry.

Comment: @Luther's answer works for me. *Edit:* On second thought, -deletes my answer-

Comment: @Julian it definitely works.  You must have some other problem; post more of your code.

Comment: ... yep, it works. My apologies.

I was editing the wrong block of code. Fail.

Comment: Pointy - $get's pretty cool, actually. It's a mootools extension written by Jens Anders Bakke.

Take a look: http://webfreak.no/wp/2007/09/05/get-for-mootools-a-way-to-read-get-variables-with-javascript-in-mootools/

Comment: @Julian - MooTools provides string extensions to deal with [querystrings](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Native/String.QueryString#String:parseQueryString). You could parse the querystring as `location.search.substr(1).parseQueryString().msgBar`. Looks a little verbose, but a wrapper function like `$get` is easy to write for the above.

Comment: Thanks, Anurag - looks great! That might be a better solution to use in conjunction with $get